# Should I include MobX store or useTranslation in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

Beginner to React apps. I have set up linting for my current React app (components are functional), and it complains about missing dependencies, sometimes a MobX store and sometimes TFunction from useTranslation.

[React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) does say that:

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes **all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect**.

Whereas [MobX's documentation](https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-effects) says that it's not needed.

Is there any way to prevent this lint warning specifically just for stores? What about useTranslation's TFunction, should it be included? It bugs me because I'd prefer not to disable this rule as a whole or disable next line and make this a norm in our code.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same question.